# Objective C - Delete files within a directory, without deleting files inside a zip

Tags: objective-c, macos, zip, nsfilemanager

how do you delete files within a directory without deleting the same files inside of a zip within that directory?

So take My Documents for example:

It contains log.txt, message.txt, button.txt, log.zip.

Inside log.zip it contains log.txt, message.txt, button.txt.

When I try to do something like this:

```
NSArray *zipFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSDocumentDirectory error:&error];
for (int i = 0; i < Files.count; i++) {
    id myArrayElement = [Files objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([myArrayElement rangeOfString:@"Button"].location !=NSNotFound || [myArrayElement rangeOfString:@"message"].location !=NSNotFound || [myArrayElement rangeOfString:@"log"].location !=NSNotFound) {
            id myArrayElement = [Files objectAtIndex:i];
            //Clean up the files in that specified directory.
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            NSString *filePath = [zipDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myArrayElement];
            BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully cleaned up files in user specified directory.");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
            }
    }
}
```

It will delete the files inside my .zip as well as the files outside of the zip which are coincidentally the same name. I want only want to delete the 3 files outside of the .zip file, not inside the .zip file.

Comment: I would suggest that you delete the body of the `if` statement, and put in an `NSLog` that prints the matching filenames. I expect that you're getting six matches, and you need to know what the matching names are.

Comment: try to replace [myArrayElement rangeOfString:@"log"].location !=NSNotFound to  [myArrayElement rangeOfString:@"log.txt"].location !=NSNotFound ;)

Comment: @stosha, I can certainly do that by it's not a very eloquent way to deal with a good way to deal with deleting files in the future. Take for example, I have hundreds of files, all called log, log1.txt, log2.txt, ...., log100.txt, hard coding is never a good habit to get into. With the program I'm writing I must account for this case, whatever the user might do.

Comment: can you insert in your code this string: NSLog(@"%@", filePath); and show us which files do you delete?

Comment: /Users/Admin/Documents/messages.txt, /Users/Admin/Documents/log.txt, /Users/Admin/Documents/Button.txt

Comment: The posted code is obviously not your real code since you get the list of files in a variable named `zipFiles` but you then reference an array named `Files` in the rest of the code. 1) Post REAL code. 2) Nothing about the posted code makes any attempt to update the contents of a zip file. You must be recreating the zip file after deleting the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are testing for your file paths containing "button", "msg" or "log". The paths "log.txt" and "log.zip" both contain "log" so you also delete your zip file.

You don't say exactly what you want to delete, all non-zip files? All .txt files? Files with names following a certain pattern? Files also contained within a ZIP in the same folder (requires accessing the ZIP contents in your code)?

If it is just .txt files you could test for `filePath.extension` being `@"txt"`, or if you wish to keep ZIP files test for it not being `@"zip"` etc. If it is names following a pattern consider `NSRegularExpression`.

HTH